# Using my own Postfix, filtering spam and getting all the mail into my ISP's inbox

Tags: postfix, spamassassin, email

I currently own a domain bought via GoDaddy.com, which provides me a basic email setup for the most common needs. I configured it to forward all mail to `me@mydomain.com` to `me@myisp.com`. I also own a virtual server with a running Postfix that I use for a specific website (all mail to `somedomain.com` gets forwarded via LMTP to a program written by me).

Since I'm recently experiencing some harassing by spammers, since GoDaddy doesn't seem to filter spam, and since my Windows Phone's Pocket Outlook cannot filter spam, I would like to use `SpamAssassin` to filter inbound spam by changing my domain's MX records to my server

## My ideal setup is the following:

1. All mail delivered to `somedomain.com` gets redirected via LMTP as usual via virtual transport **without any spam check**
2. All mail to `me@mydomain.com` gets redirected to `me@myisp.com` after a **severe spam check**
3. I don't care about `otheraddress@mydomain.com` since I use just one address for now
4. I would like to train SpamAssassin with customized spam rules, possibly based on the presence of certain keywords (links to certain unsubscribe pages I found recurring)

I currently configured Postfix with

transport

```
somedomain.com                 lmtp:[127.0.0.1]:8025
.somedomain.com                error: Cannot accept mail for this domain
```

relay

```
somedomain.com                 OK
```

(I guess I should add `mydomain.com OK` too)

virtual

```
@mydomain.com                  me@myisp.com
```

(looks like a catch-all rule, it's OK as requirement 3)

I installed SpamAssassin, I can do `rcspamd start` and set it to boot with the server, but I don't know if there is anything else to do for use in Postfix, and how to apply requirement 1 (only mail to mydomain.com gets filtered)

I also tried to send an email via Telnet to make sure my settings are ready for MX change. I received the message into my account but I found that it gone through secureserver.net, like Postfix didn't rewrite the destination but simply relayed the message.

Thank you in advance. I'm no expert in SpamAssassin, and I have little experience in Postfix (enough to avoid making my server an *open relay*)

Answer (score 1):

Have you set SpamAssassin as a **content-filter** or **smtpd_proxy_filter**?

Postfix needs to know how to talk to SpamAssassin. I've always used Postfix with some kind of SMTP-Proxy (like [Amavis](http://www.ijs.si/software/amavisd/) or [VBoxAdm](http://developer.gauner.org/vboxadm/)) so I'm not sure whether SpamAssassin ships with a SMTP-Proxy of its own. Figure this out and use content-filter if you want Post-Queue filtering or smtpd_proxy_filter if you want Pre-Queue filtering. In the case of the pre-queue filter the smtp proxy needs a way to re-inject the mail, so you have to create a new transport in the master.cf. A content-filter is set in the main.cf while a smtpd_proxy_filter must be set in the master.cf.

Comment: I didn't set it yet. I just installed it via YaST (openSUSE)